# AT command error while sending sms

Tags: at-command

I use AT+CMGS on ubuntu and use ctrl + z but its give me an error

[image]

i use this command in ubuntu command line to connect gsm modem

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Comment: Please update your question to have the modem communication as pure text and not an image (and format it as code).

Comment: Enable extended error reporting with `AT+CMEE=2` so you get a more descriptive error than just `ERROR`.

Comment: I use `AT+CMEE=2`  but nothing change and just back a just on `ERROR`

Answer (score 1):

Check if network is proper.
AT+CSQ
AT+CREG?

Is the SMS Center no set correctly?

Comment: I use AT command with on windows with putty and it send message without any problem

Answer (score 1):

The **+xx** country code should not be included in the command, at least for the modem I use in work ([ZTE 190](https://www.cnet.com/products/zte-mf190-wireless-cellular-modem/), if I remember). For example, Brazil's code is +55. So for example: Sending SMS for the city of Belo Horizonte, Brazil:

```
AT+CMGS=31#########
```

...CR, then the message and ctrl+z. The service center code includes the country code, at least for the Brazil's SMS service centers I saw [on this page](https://docs.makerplanet.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2883698).

**Checking Service Center Configuration**

Did you set the Service Center? [AT+CSCA](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcsca-sms-service-center-address/)? command checks for that. The country code is included in this step, as far as I could understand, within the Service Center code. Check the image in the link [AT+CSCA](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcsca-sms-service-center-address/) and you'll see the **+xx**, which I believe is the country code.

If the problem persists, also:

**Check Character Set Configuration**

I'd recommend using [AT+CSCS](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcscs-select-te-character-set/) for setting GSM mode, according to the format of your provided command example. If you send...

```
AT+CSCS?
```

... your modem will asnwer the current config. You can check if your modem supports GSM by sending:

```
AT+CSCS=?
```

Note the **=** differing from the previous command.

As far as I know, GSM is limited to the [charset available here](https://dev.infobip.com/docs/language).

**More fonts:**

https://www.developershome.com/sms/operatingMode.asp

https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcmgs-send-sms-message/

Answer (score 0):

AT+CSCA is used to define the SMS center number.
Neverthless, you are successfull in sending the SMS using windows. 
I dont know if it is terminal problem. Can you try with minicom?
Download minicom for linux and set it up.
After installing minicom, give "minicom -e"
Choose the port and baud rate and give commands.For sure, the Module is register (AT+CREG?) and please enable the ERROR AT+CMEE=1

Sometimes error comes if message memory is full.
Give AT+CMGD =1,4 and try again.

Let me know the result!